# Not able to run python as admin

Tags: python

I am new to python.

I am creating a python script which need to run as admin as I want to set system time. I have searched on other questions and come up the solution like this:

```
import ctypes, sys

def check_is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False
        
if check_is_admin():
      
    with open("testingAdmin.txt", "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write('this is admin')
else:
    print('this is not admin')
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
```

As I read on other's answer, it said i need to run on cmd with `py "isAdmin.py"`  but when i run it, a dialog asking for permission pop out, but nothing happens after I press yes.

Is there anything i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help. I am also new to python, However it worked for me and
I took this code from stackoverflow only.
So if it works no credit is needed.
There are alot of codes available it took me more then 5 hours to find the correct one.

```
import os ,sys , win32com.shell.shell as shell
Asadmin = 'asadmin'
if sys.argv[-1] != Asadmin:
    script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
    params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [Asadmin])
   shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas',lpFile=sys.executablelpParameters=params)
   print("succesful")
   sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: If you took the code from another answer, please link to the original answer.

Comment: I don't remember that page, its been long time.